# XSLT conditionally change text font

Tags: xslt

For the following xml,

```
         <question>     
            <bp>Suppose a file a.xml has content:</bp>
            <bp><![CDATA[<a> 1 <b> 2 <b> 3 <a> 4 </a> </b> </b> </a>]]></bp>
            <bp>What is the value of the following XPath expression:</bp>
             <bp>for $x in doc("a.xml")//a/b return $x/b/a/text()</bp>
        </question>
```

In the XSLT file, I have to change the font of the text if the text between the xml tags contains

```
    <![CDATA[ ]]>
```

I tried using the following code,

```
        <xsl:for-each select="mcq:bp">
            <xsl:if test="contains(. , '<![CDATA[ ]]>')">
                 <xsl:attribute name='font-family'>courier</xsl:attribute>
                 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <br/>                               
            </xsl:for-each>
```

But the xslt does not display anything in the browser.

Comment: There are no XML tags within the CDATA section. The purpose of CDATA is to say "the things in here might look like XML tags, but they are not." If you want them parsed as XML, don't wrap them in CDATA.

Answer (score 1):

**This cannot be done with XSLT**.

At the time XSLT is passed the parsed XML document, there isn't any information whether a text node contained CDATA sections or not -- this lexical detail is stripped-off (lost) as result of the parsing of the XML document.

**CDATA isn't a string and it isn't part of the text node.** Therefore, it is wrong to try to detect a CDATA section by using the `contains()` function.

Comment: @Michael Kay

Thanks for the response.

I was wondering if I modified the xml as follows.
                      <bp><code><![CDATA[]></code></bp>

In XSLT how can I formt the text in CDATA to change its font to "courier"